# Find some solution $w$ which is not divided by any divisor of $a^{2x}$ and $b^{2y}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Let us consider the following conguence:
$$2^{x+z}b^{y}(2a^{x}+b^{y})w=0  \bmod 2^{x}a^{2x}$$
$$ 2^{y+z}a^{x}(a^{x}+2b^{y})w=0  \bmod 2^{y}b^{2y}$$

I am asking if it is possible to find some solution $w$ which is not divided by any divisor of $a^{2x}$ and $b^{2y}$.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry if i'm misinterpreting here, but you can find a solution $w$ for any two integers $a$ and $b$ by breaking them down into their prime factors and choosing a prime number that is not one of them. As there are an infinite amount of prime numbers, you'll always be able to find one.

Comment: Can you elaborate with your idea.

Comment: Do you want a formula for w? I didn't fully understand the question.

Comment: I just want to see how you can find $w$ by some steps.

Comment: ab+1 would work. let's take an example:

Comment: $a=2, b=3, x=1, y=1$. all the divisors of $a^{2x}$ are composed of factors of $a$, so $x$ doesn't matter. same with $y$. by multiplying $a\cdot b$ gives a number with all the factors of $a$ and $b$, and then we add 1 ensuring none of those factors are in $w$. I hope that clears it up.

Comment: Yes. But I am asking if $ab+1$ works in my example.

Comment: Yes, it should always work.